# Grails Spring Security - User and Role tables are wiped whenever the application restarts

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security

I'm storing user details in a MySQL database, but whenever the application restarts, all users and roles are lost. I initially thought it was this part in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
UserRole.withSession {
   it.flush()
   it.clear()
}
```

But commenting that out hasn't had any impact on the situation. Furthermore, any modifications (additional fields) I make to the user table are also gone when the application restarts. Since I'm fairly new to Grails, I don't yet know where else I could look for this behavior to disable it. What other files could this be taking place in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `dbCreate` in your datasource configuration is `create-drop` (it drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly).

Change it to `update` (Creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data).

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#_more_on_dbcreate